# python loop over asynchronously updated list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, asynchronous

I've got a list called "current_data" that is updated asynchronously.

If I simply run a loop over it that prints the last record it repeats the same list without considering the subsequent insertions.

so, if I run in Jupyter "current_data" it does show the updates

However, if I run a loop over the "current_data" list the list in the loop remains the same as per the first iteration:

```
for n in range(1, 10000):
    print(current_data[-1])
```

How can I loop over the list? Is it necessary to "+=" a function?

Comment: So you are using a global variable to communicate between multiple parallel execution threads?

Comment: Are you sure it's the same `current_list` and not a different variable of the same name? You can check using `print(id(current_list))` and checking that the numbers match

Comment: Jan Wilamowski: yes

Comment: That is not a good way of handling this sort of communication. Depending on your use case, you could use either messaging with subscriptions or a queuing system.